# Does Tensorflow Dataset shuffle between epochs with Dataset transforms after shuffle?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am working on a TensorFlow pipeline where I load a bunch of signals into a Dataset, I shuffle those signals, then do windowing on the signals, and then batch and repeat. This dataset is used to train a tf.keras model with the model.fit function call. It is very important that the windows of the signal are not shuffled, which is why this is the order of the Dataset transforms.

I am wondering if the order of the signals will be shuffled in between epochs? I have found that `dataset.shuffle().batch().repeat()` will make shuffle the dataset between epochs, but this will not work for my application, since I need to do windowing and other transforms after the shuffling.

I am using TensorFlow version 1.13.1.

```
#... some pre-processing on the signals 
signalList = [...] # a list of tuples (data, label)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: signalList)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=self.buffer_size)  ## will this shuffle be repeated??
dataset = dataset.map(...) # windowing and other transforms
dataset = dataset.batch()
dataset = dataset.repeat()

model.fit(dataset, ...)
```

Edit: the behavior I am interested in is that I would like the order of the signals to be re-shuffled with every epoch. So, if I have 3 signals

```
signal0=[window0_0,window0_1]
signal1=[window1_0,window1_1,window1_2]
signal2=[window2_0]
```

then the output would look something like this:

```
tf.Tensor([signal0,signal2,signal1],...) # equivalent to tf.Tensor([window0_0,window0_1,window2_0,window1_0,window1_1,window1_2])
tf.Tensor([signal1,signal0,signal2],...) # equivalent to tf.Tensor([window1_0,window1_1,window1_2,window0_0,window0_1,window2_0])
```

where the transform datset.map(windowing).shuffle().batch().repeat() would produce something like this (which I am not interested in)

```
tf.Tensor([window0_1,window1_1,window2_0,window1_0,window0_0,window1_2])
tf.Tensor([window0_0,window1_2,window0_1,window2_0,window1_1,window1_0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of investigation, I've realized that yes, the `shuffle` is called after every epoch, even if there are other transforms after the shuffle and before the batch. I'm unsure about what that means for the pipeline (as in, I'm not sure if the windowing is also called in every epoch and is slowing down the processing), but I created a jupyter notebook where I created a small version of the pipeline

```
signalList = [...] # a list of tuples (data, label)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(lambda: signalList)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=self.buffer_size)  
dataset = dataset.map(...) # windowing and other transforms
dataset = dataset.batch()
dataset = dataset.repeat()
```

created an iterator

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

and plotted the signals for a few epochs

```
next_ = iterator.get_next()
for i in range(10):  # 10 epochs
    full_signal = []
    for j in range(29):  # 29 events for this epoch
        next_ = iterator.get_next()
        full_signal = np.concatenate((full_signal, next_[0][0]), axis=None)

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5))
    plt.plot(full_signal)
```

and saw that the signals looked like they were always in a different order, which would mean that they are getting re-shuffled after every epoch.

If anyone has a more detailed answer, where they can explain how this works with how DatasetAPI compiles, or if they can clarify if the order of these transforms slow down the pipeline, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an optional argument to `.shuffle()` to prevent reshuffling each epoch.

So, if i have a dataset like this:

```py
def gen():
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, output_shapes=(), output_types=tf.int32)
```

then doing:

```py
shuffled_and_batched = ds.shuffle(3).batch(3).repeat()
```

gives output:

```
tf.Tensor([3 2 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 1 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 1 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 3 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

where each epoch reorders my 3 elements. This is the behaviour I understand you want to avoid.

If, instead, I do:

```
shuffled_and_batched = ds.shuffle(3, reshuffle_each_iteration=False).batch(3).repeat()
```

then I get the output:

```
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([1 3 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

with the ordering shuffled once and then reused each epoch.

Comment: The former (shuffling between epochs) is the behavior that I want. However, I want to shuffle the signals, not the windows, which is why I do shuffle, then window, then batch, then repeat. if instead of `shuffled_and_batched = ds.shuffle(3).batch(3).repeat()`, I do `shuffled_and_windowed_and_batched = ds.shuffle(3).map(windowing function).batch(3).repeat()`, will it also reshuffle between epochs? Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: does that make sense? let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: So epoch 1 you have somethign like `[a,b,c], [f,d,e], [i,g,h]` and next epoch you want it shuffled to something like: `[[f,d,e], [i,g,h], [a,b,c]]`? If so then you need a shuffle to come *after* the window function: `ds.map(windowing function).shuffle(100, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(3).repeat()`

Comment: Yes, I think that's it. Thank you! What you're saying is `ds.map(windowing).shuffle(100, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(3).repeat()` will only shuffle the events, and not the windows inside of the events, even though the events have already been windowed?

Comment: that's right, but I am curious, do you know if the shuffle will repeat in the case of `ds.shuffle(100,reshuffle_each_iteration=True).map(windowing).batch(3).repeat()`? It sounds like what you suggested is more efficient, but I'm curious about if what I have implemented is supposed to work or if it's just a fluke